# nginx windows: website only reachable with localhost, not when using IP-address

Tags: windows, nginx

I am running an nginx (v. 1.20.1) proxy on my windows machine. The following is the `nginx.conf`:

```
http {
  include       mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;

  sendfile        on;
  keepalive_timeout  65;

  server {
      listen       *:80;
      server_name  localhost;

    
      location / {
          proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
      }

      error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
      location = /50x.html {
          root   html;
      }
  }
}
```

When I type `localhost` in my browser I get the correct response.

When I use my IP-adress however it says that the website can not be reached.

I've tried allowing external access on port 80 as well as access for the `nginx.exe` in the Windows Defender Firewall. I also deactivated the firewall in my Kaspersky Internet Security.

Any ideas what the problem is?

Comment: `server_name  localhost;` means Listen for "localhost" and nothing else - either use \_default\_ meaning an invalid name to listen to any names or use like  server_name  localhost 192.168.1.1;

Answer (score 0):

you need to enable ip access control to access it.

check this link for more steps: [link](https://help.cloud66.com/node/how-to-guides/security/nginx-deny.html) and this [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/351559/nginx-without-server-name-and-using-only-static-ip-address)

Comment: First links seems like an approach but I don't want to whitelist any ip-addresses. What if I want it to be open for everyone? I tried adding only my ip-address but now calling `localhost` leads to `403 Forbidden`.
Because of the second link I added `_` for `server_name` but it didn't help.